# Is there an easy method of finding Validators relating to an input control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I've been searching Google for the past couple of hours to try an find a way of returning all Validators relating to an input control. Maybe I'm phrasing incorrectly or its not possible.

I know that there is a collection of validators accessible via Page.Validators, but what I want to do is something like this:

```
var myValidators = Page.Validators.Where(x => x.ControlToValidate = "abcdef");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Page.Validators` holds a collection of `IValidator`, but most validators derive from `BaseValidator`, which has the `ControlToValidate` property, so you can do this:

```
var myValidators = Page.Validators.OfType<BaseValidator>
                                  .Where(x => x.ControlToValidate == "abcdef");
```

Comment: One thing to remember with the above solution (or any using the ControlToValidate field), is that the ControlId name must be linked with a naming container/user control, otherwise you'll end up with duplicates.